# Define namespace across different files

Tags: typescript

Simple question but could not find a solution yet.
I want to split a namespace across multiple `.ts` files.

**File 1:** `parameter1.ts`:

```
namespace Parameters {
  export const parameter1 = {
    param1: 1,
    param2: 2,
    param3: 3,
  };
}

export { Parameters };
```

**File 2:** `parameter2.ts`:

```
namespace Parameters {
  export const parameter2 = {
    param1: 1,
    param2: 2,
    param3: 3,
  };
}

export { Parameters };
```

If I now want to use the namespace `Parameters` in another file, both exports are displayed separately in autocomplete.

```
Parameters.parameter1 
Parameters.parameter2
// The two namespaces Parameters are not merged together
```

Is it possible to use namespaces across different files as I would like?

### EDIT:

Tried new setups:

#### Setup 1:

`param1.ts`:

```
namespace Parameter.Global{
    export const param1 = 1;
}
```

`param2.ts`:

```
namespace Parameter.Global{
    export const param2 = 2;
}
```

`index.ts`:

```
console.log(Parameter.Global.param1);
console.log(Parameter.Global.param2);
```

This time, my IDE throws no error but the browser after compiling;

**Uncaught ReferenceError: Parameter is not defined**

#### Setup 2:

Added `reference` in `index.ts`.

`param1.ts`:

```
namespace Parameter.Global{
    export const param1 = 1;
}
```

`param2.ts`:

```
namespace Parameter.Global{
    export const param2 = 2;
}
```

`index.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="param1.ts" />
/// <reference path="param2.ts" />

console.log(Parameter.Global.param1);
console.log(Parameter.Global.param2);
```

But this does not work as well.

**index.ts:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: Parameter is not defined**

Comment: Does this help? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Comment: iirc namespaces didn't work well with modules.
"Either namespaces, or exports, choose one" or something.

Comment: In modules, namespaces are just seperate objects. In non-module they got merged by merging files into one, and modules are not merged, they are standalone. That's also why namespaces had ///ref -s to determine execution order.